Can Someone explain why function 1 is so much slower than function 2?
I have a function that accepts a sorted list of values and computes unique IDs for each input value.
For example:
input : [2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6]
output: [0,0,1,2,3,3,3,4]

To do that i have written that function a while ago:
def mapHashedIdsToIds(hashed_ids):
    unique_section_ids = []
    uniqueHashedIds = []
    idMapping = {}
    currentId = 0

    for element in hashed_ids:
        if element not in idMapping:
            idMapping[element] = currentId
            currentId += 1
            uniqueHashedIds.append(element)

    for element in hashed_ids:
        unique_section_id = idMapping[element]
        unique_section_ids.append(unique_section_id)

    return(unique_section_ids)

unique_ids = mapHashedIdsToIds(uniqueAbschnittsId)

Now, upon revisiting the code, I aimed to simplify the function with the following attempt:
def Generate_unique_sectionid(hashed_ids):
    already_used_hashed_ids = []
    unique_section_ids = []
    for element in hashed_ids:
        if element not in already_used_hashed_ids:
            already_used_hashed_ids.append(element)
            unique_section_ids.append(len(already_used_hashed_ids)-1)
        else:
            unique_section_ids.append(len(already_used_hashed_ids)-1)
    return unique_section_ids

unique_ids = Generate_unique_sectionid(uniqueAbschnittsId)

I tested both functions using the %timeit command in Jupyter Notebook. Surprisingly, my new function took 2.8 seconds to execute, while the old one only took 25.1 milliseconds. What could be causing this significant difference in computing time? What am I overlooking? I would have expected my new approach to be much faster since it only involves one loop, no dictionary, and no counter variable.
I appreciate your thoughts!

With what sample data was it so slow? It runs fine on my computer with the data in your question

Its a list with around 1000 hash numbers. Both functions are fine yes. the first one is just significantly slower than the new one.

Sorry, communication problem, when I said "runs fine" I meant quickly. Note In your question you say the second one is slower.

Even with a list of 1000 values Generate_unique_sectionid runs in milliseconds on my computer

But do you also have this huge difference between both functions? I maybe found a solution. Maybe its the difference between searching if the value is in a dict(version1) and in a list(version 2).

maybe problem is because first version uses set - idMapping = {} - which can works faster than list - already_used_hashed_ids = []. OR maybe you should print() or profiler to see which part of code is executed and how fast it works. Maybe first version doesn't work as you expect - maybe it skips some elements - and this makes it faster.

In the first function: You are using a dictionary, lookup and insertion operations are generally O(1) on average in dictionaries. So, the overall time complexity of the function will be O(n) for n elements.
In the second function: You are using a list, 'not in' operation has a linear time complexity O(n), so overall time complexity will be O(n^2)for n elements

That's it. Thank you! I used a set instead of a list and now version 2 is faster than 1.

It appears that the issue if with already_used_hashed_ids.
In the first snippet, the values are stored as dictionary, meaning that under the hood they were using hash tables. It's much faster to allocate value's precence this way (complexity is O(1)), than if it's stored in a list (complexity is O(n)). Switching a type of already_used_hashed_ids to set solves this issue.
Also, consider rewriting a code a bit, as you have unique_section_ids.append(len(already_used_hashed_ids)-1) executed in each branch of an if.
